# Installer/uninstalling tool

Tags: c#, windows, installation, uninstallation

At work i often have to uninstall a version of the company's software before installing another version from a different server. This process seems a bit of timewasting. So my question is :
Is it possible to write a small tool in C# (visual studio) where you select the desired server (URL where you download a setup file), and the tool then does all the work for you like uninstalling the previous version, deletes a folder in regedit and installs the new version?

What kind of methods can i use to make this happen?

I'm still a rookie at programming, so this project could gain me some useful experience which i actually can use in a real life working situation ;-)

Hope you will help me out with a few guidelines here :)

Comment: You can write that functionality into your installer so it uninstalls automatically while installing the new version.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

As eddie_cat said, the install package can be configured or scripted to do things like uninstalling the old software and cleaning up registry files. For more detail on how to do that, we'd need to know the nature of that software; is it also a .NET program, and what install technology are you using (VS Install Project, InstallShield, WiX, etc).

If the program you are installing and uninstalling is also a .NET program, you could set it up as a ClickOnce deployment. The application will be deployed within a bootstrapper which will check for updates to the software on each app startup, based on a server URL configured into the deployment package (which can be different from the download URL). If it finds one, it will alert the user, who has the option to install or skip the update. Downloading and installation are handled automatically.

Downsides are that you have to digitally sign the application assemblies and ClickOnce manifest so ClickOnce can verify the upgrade and replace the older version instead of creating a brand new installation, ClickOnce only installs into a user-specific app directory, not into the "All Users" Program Files directory, and you cannot have any user-customizable install settings like installing various components or "sidechaining" additional package installs (besides prerequisites).